# What is the meaning of VERY in phrases such as...the VERY first [noun]...?

Tags: adverbs

1.

> > ...from my **very** first day

2.

> > ...at the **very** first stage

3.

> > ...from the **very** first touches

4.

> > The **very** first canon of nursing

Are they adverbs?

What is the meaning of VERY in phrases such as...the VERY first [noun]...?

For what purpose are they placed before adjectives?

Comment: Did you look it up in a dictionary?  The definition is the second one here:  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/very

Comment: Yes, my dictionary says that too but it's [very + superlative].

Comment: It may be helpful to think of *very* as an emphasizer (i.e., it emphasizes a quality or a thing), as opposed to "hugely" or "abundantly" as it may happen in your first language. (A lot of *very SOMETHING* instances make more sense when I translate them to *a lot of SOMETHING* in my first language.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We call **very** an **adverb of degree**. It strengthens the adjective or adverb it modifies. In addition to your examples, we might say:

> It is **very** cold outside.
>   The engine is running **very** smoothly.

The negative form is used as well to modify an adjective; just use **not** before **very**:

> We are **not very** happy.

Comment: Thank you. I look it up in the dictionary. There is another usage [very + adj] like "very French", "very wrong". So I am a bit confused about it. Because [very + adj + noun] looks similar to that.

Comment: The part which confuses me is that "the very first touches" is of the form [the very + adj + noun]. It's not just  [very + adj].

Comment: @user9418 Very + adj is exactly the usage I describe here. In "He is very French," "French" is an adjective. What confuses you? If a noun comes after the adjective, that does not change the meaning of "very." E.g., "He is a very young man." You may be referring to the use of "very" as an **adjective** indicating the superlative, as in "This is the very top of the mountain." That is not the usage of "very" in your question.

Comment: Because both forms [very + adj with/without noun] and [very + adj WITHOUT noun] are in different entries in the dictionary. Now I understand that. Thank you. I do appreciate it.

Comment: @user9418 This sounds like a **very** confusing dictionary to me! What dictionary is it?

Comment: The dictionary I have is Collins COBUILD English Dictionary for Advanced Learners in 3rd edition which is not a **very** recent edition and in fair condition. But it is still great compared to later editions. I think what is confusing to you is not this dictionary, but my presentation of my question. Sorry about that! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @user9418 Don't apologize. Whatever your native tongue, you are already better at my language than I probably am at yours!

Answer (score 0):

In a phrase like *very first*, it's used for emphasis, but I wouldn't describe it as an adverb of degree; the first member of a sequence cannot be more first or less first!

I think this usage is akin to that of “This is the very thing I'm looking for” or “This is the very place where something happened”; the meaning is more like ‘exact’ (compare Latin *verum* ‘true’, French *vrai*).

Comment: Food for thought. Is _first_ here an adjective or a noun used as descriptor? To me, it seems to be an adjective, and if it is, _very_ is an adverb. "The _very best_ thing." "The _very first_ thing."

Comment: But does _very_ modify the adjective alone, or the noun phrase {first thing}?  I'm leaning to say it's more the latter.